# ¿Cómo alternar Colores en Java?

Tags: java, netbeans

Creo arcos mediante un ciclo For, busco alternar el color para que se distingan, cómo podría hacerlo cambiando el color con el ciclo for? Utilizo la clase paint para ello.

```
g.setColor(new Color(255,0,0);
g.fillArc(25, 80, 250, 250, gradosInicio, grado);
```

Comment: ¿Podrías explicar un poco más detalladamente el problema? Sobre todo indicar el resultado esperado y añadir algo más de código de lo que has puesto para que la gente que vaya a responderte pueda probar el código en su equipo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No se si te refieres exactamente a lo que te voy a comentar, corrígeme si me equivoco.

La solución que yo te doy es hacer un Random de los valores enteros de los colores RGB dentro de un bucle. Para que se distingan puedes almacenar en un ArrayList aquel color generado aleatoriamente, para que en el siguiente color generado, no sea igual al ya usado (una validación). A ver, en este punto mencionar que si te sale un aleatorio por ejemplo: 220, 86, 78 y el siguiente color pregenerado aleatoriamente es 220, 86, 77; son colores distintos aunque el ojo humano no lo va a notar. Una solución a este problema podría ser que tu pregeneraras un ArrayList con colores ***claramente diferenciados*** e ir extrayendo estos colores. Por ejemplo, imaginate que tu vas a crear arcos de colores con un maximo de 8 colores, almacenas 8 colores claramente diferenciados para el ojo humano en un arrayList [yo escribo el nombre, pero tu tendrías que almacenar un objeto Color(int,int,int)]:

```
(Rojo, Azul, Amarillo, rosa, morado, verde, naranja, cían)
```

Según avances tu bucle vas seleccionando uno a uno cada color.

**La otra solución** al problema de colores idénticos al ojo humano seria establecer una validación de los campos RGB, donde al menos una de las 3 variables difiera en al menos 20 unidades (tanto hacia arriba como hacia abajo teniendo en cuenta que el mínimo es 0 y el maximo 255) que sería suficiente para que el ojo humano capte la diferencia.

Un saludo y espero haberte ayudado.